# How to specify the --dist_dir when building Android kernel

Tags: android, ubuntu, build, kernel

I copied the build command from the following doc:

https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building-kernels

**Here is the build command:**

```
tools/bazel build //common:kernel_aarch64_dist -- --dist_dir=out/dist
```

**Here is the error:**

```
ERROR: Skipping '-dist_dir=out/dist': couldn't determine target from filename '-dist_dir=out/dist'
ERROR: couldn't determine target from filename '-dist_dir=out/dist'
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.158s
INFO: 0 processes.
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I have tried to create the "`out/dist`" first, and also tried to replace it with "`/tmp/dist`", but the error is the same "`couldn't determine target from filename`".

How to specify the `--dist_dir` when building Android kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `run` to create a distribution, for example

```
tools/bazel run //common:kernel_aarch64_dist -- --dist_dir=out/dist
```